# Armory and segwit addresses

Tags: segregated-witness, armory

I'm using Ledger wallet, and it recently prompted me to migrate to new Segwit address type. If I want to use Segwit transactions from Armory, do I have to do something similar (I have installed bitcoin 0.15)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use Armory 0.96.2 and be in expert mode. When you go to request new addresses, there will be an option for you to choose P2SH-P2WPKH addresses. When you send Bitcoin, you can also choose to make your change P2SH-P2WPKH.